# Can't get XSL to handle multiple elements that have no attributes without getting duplicates

Tags: xml, xslt

I am new to XSLT. I have to do a style sheet for EHR. Here is a cut down version of the XML:

```
<Message>
    <MSH>
        <Id>1</Id>
    </MSH>
    <PID>
        <Id>2</Id>
    </PID>
    <ORC>
        <Id>3</Id>
        <PlacerOrderId>ORD723222-4</PlacerOrderId>
    </ORC>
    <OBR>
        <Id>4</Id>
        <OBRSetid>1</OBRSetid>
    </OBR>
    <OBX>
        <Id>5</Id>
        <OBXSetId>1</OBXSetId>
    </OBX>
    <OBX>
        <Id>6</Id>
        <OBXSetId>2</OBXSetId>
    </OBX>
    <OBX>
        <Id>7</Id>
        <OBXSetId>3</OBXSetId>
    </OBX>
    <SPM>
        <Id>8</Id>
        <SPBSetId>1</SPBSetId>
    </SPM>
    <ORC>
        <Id>9</Id>
        <PlacerOrderId/>
    </ORC>
    <OBR>
        <Id>10</Id>
        <OBRSetid>2</OBRSetid>
    </OBR>
    <OBX>
        <Id>11</Id>
        <OBXSetId>1</OBXSetId>
    </OBX>
    <OBX>
        <Id>12</Id>
        <OBXSetId>2</OBXSetId>
    </OBX>
    <OBX>
        <Id>13</Id>
        <OBXSetId>3</OBXSetId>
    </OBX>
    <ORC>
        <Id>14</Id>
        <PlacerOrderId/>
    </ORC>
    <OBR>
        <Id>15</Id>
        <OBRSetid>3</OBRSetid>
    </OBR>
    <OBX>
        <Id>16</Id>
        <OBXSetId>1</OBXSetId>
    </OBX>
    <OBX>
        <Id>17</Id>
        <OBXSetId>2</OBXSetId>
    </OBX>
    <OBX>
        <Id>18</Id>
        <OBXSetId>3</OBXSetId>
    </OBX>
    <ORC>
        <Id>19</Id>
        <PlacerOrderId/>
    </ORC>
    <OBR>
        <Id>20</Id>
        <OBRSetid>4</OBRSetid>
    </OBR>
    <OBX>
        <Id>21</Id>
        <OBXSetId>1</OBXSetId>
    </OBX>
    <OBX>
        <Id>22</Id>
        <OBXSetId>2</OBXSetId>
    </OBX>
    <OBX>
        <Id>23</Id>
        <OBXSetId>3</OBXSetId>
    </OBX>
</Message>
```

I created the following xslt just to get the ORC and OBR working first:

```
<xsl:for-each select="ORC">
    <xsl:value-of select="Id"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="PlacerOrderId"/>
</xsl:for-each>
<xsl:for-each select="OBR">
    <xsl:value-of select="Id"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="OBRSetid"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

They come out with all the ORC values followed by all the OBR values. I want it to do the first ORC values followed by the first OBR values, then the sets of OBX values, etc. the same sequence as the xml. I tried to nest the OBR for-each in the ORC, but that didn't work as all the OBR values come out after the first set of ORC values.

How do I code it to come out in the same sequence as the xml, instead of pulling all the values at once for each element?

Comment: Please add the expected output XML for your sample input to remove any ambiguity.

Comment: You are right, I should have done that. However, Joel came up with it below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe you want something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="/Message/*[self::ORC or self::OBR or self::OBX]"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ORC">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:value-of select="Id"/><xsl:text> </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="PlacerOrderId"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="OBR">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:value-of select="Id"/><xsl:text> </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="OBRSetid"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="OBX">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:value-of select="Id"/><xsl:text> </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="OBXSetid"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

based on your input, it produces:

```
<ORC>3 ORD723222-4</ORC>
<OBR>4 1</OBR>
<OBX>5 </OBX>
<OBX>6 </OBX>
<OBX>7 </OBX>
<ORC>9 </ORC>
<OBR>10 2</OBR>
<OBX>11 </OBX>
<OBX>12 </OBX>
<OBX>13 </OBX>
<ORC>14 </ORC>
<OBR>15 3</OBR>
<OBX>16 </OBX>
<OBX>17 </OBX>
<OBX>18 </OBX>
<ORC>19 </ORC>
<OBR>20 4</OBR>
<OBX>21 </OBX>
<OBX>22 </OBX>
<OBX>23 </OBX>
```

Comment: That works well. Thank you! One more thing I need help on is to make a table of OBX. I have the table body working, but I cannot figure out how to get the table header in there without it repeating. Any idea where to place the table header?

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow! If you find an answer helpful or the most helpful of all answers, you can mark the answer as accepted by ticking the arrow on the left to make it appear green (just below the arrowheads).

Comment: With regards to your second question, you can create another question here. Just post your input XML, your required output and what have you tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

what you want is probably something like that

```
<xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="/Message/node()"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ORC">
    <xsl:value-of select="Id"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="PlacerOrderId"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="OBR">
    <xsl:value-of select="Id"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="OBRSetid"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="node()">
</xsl:template>
```

Then you can add new template to match OBX, and so on.

hope this help.
regards,
Yann